# Should we close this question as a duplicate or attempt to answer it?

Tags: discussion

It's similar to other questions (which philip and I have linked).  Do we think it is sufficiently different to stay open?

[Ways to incapacitate an opponent with little force?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13226/ways-to-incapacitate-an-opponent-with-little-force)

Answer (score 1):

If you think a question might be a duplicate, then vote to close it. The poll will be the votes to close, and others can still answer if they want.